# Android. ArrayAdapter. "The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification."

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an issue with a listview. Some users have crashes with a following trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.a.b.c)]
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1779)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3264)
   at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:4098)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5568)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2069)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1737)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:6272)
   at android.widget.ListView.dispatchTouchEvent(ListView.java:4820)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2075)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2075)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2075)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2075)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2075)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2075)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1751)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1998)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1410)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2433)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1946)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5748)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3170)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2724)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:951)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:965)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2700)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5109)
```

But I'm sure the content in the ArrayList has not be changed. Code:

```
public class ArchivedEventListFragment extends ListFragment {

    ArrayList<Event> mEvents;
    ...
    EventArrayAdapter mEventsAdapter;
    DataManager mDataManager;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        mDataManager = DataManager.get(getActivity());
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.archive_list_fragment, container, false);
        ...
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mEvents == null) {
            mEvents = mDataManager.getArchivedEvents();
            if (mEvents.isEmpty()) {
                new DownloadArchive().execute();
            } else if (mEventsAdapter == null) {
                mEventsAdapter = new EventArrayAdapter(mEvents);
                setListAdapter(mEventsAdapter);
            } else if (getListAdapter() == null) {
                setListAdapter(mEventsAdapter);
            } else {
                mEventsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        if (getListAdapter() != null && mEventsAdapter != null) {
            mEventsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        getListView().clearChoices();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ...
    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {

        ...
    }

    private class EventArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

        private final ArrayList<Event> events;

        public EventArrayAdapter(ArrayList<Event> sourceEvents) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, sourceEvents);

            events = sourceEvents;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list_item, parent, false);

                ...

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Event event = getItem(position);

            ...
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return events.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Event getItem(int position) {
            return events.get(position);
        }
    }

    private class DownloadArchive extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Event>> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Event> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return mDataManager.getArchivedEvents();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            setListAdapter(null);
            mEventsAdapter = null;
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Event> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (isAdded()) {
                mEvents = result;
                if (!(mEvents.isEmpty())) {
                    mEventsAdapter = new EventArrayAdapter(mEvents);
                    setListAdapter(mEventsAdapter);
                } else {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    mDataManager.clearEvents();
                    new DownloadArchive().execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
```

}

I tried to invoke adpater.notifydatasetchanget everywhere in the code but it didn't help. Please help me understand where is my fault.

Comment: There are lots of issues I have with your logic in the program. I can go over them if you'd like. However, since you asked about one specific issue, I'm gonna make a few assumptions here. It seems you have some singleton object DataManager that you store your events in. What I think is happening is that somewhere else, in some other class you're modifying the events in mDataManager. Because that list of events there is the one backing the one stored in the adapter, Android is complaining you updated list without notifying it.

Comment: I ask DataManager for events once and save them in a new ArrayList. Why do changes in DataManager ArrayList may affect ArrayList in this code?

Comment: I'm hoping you know a bit of java. The point is that really you probably only ever created one `ArrayList`. How many times do you have `new ArrayList<>()`? Probably only in your `DataManager`. In the code you posted, you never actually created a `new ArrayList`. So your adapter here is actually using the `ArrayList` in `DataManager`. If you update that `ArrayList` anywhere else, in any other code, it causes problems here.

Comment: You are right, I'm a beginner in Java. I thought that 
`ArrayList<Event> mEvents;
mEvents = mDataManager.getArchivedEvents();`
creates a new ArrayList and copies data from the DataManager.

Comment: It doesn't create a new list actually, `mEvents` just points to the `ArrayList` that `DataManager` returns. Imagine you have `Object o1 = new Object()`, `Object o2 = o1`. Clearly there is only one object (only one `new` statement). `o2` just points to the same object as `o1`. That's what's happening in your case.

Comment: Thank you! The most likely you are right and this is the reason.